# What is SQL Server 2008 R2's alternative to Oracle 11g RAC?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, oracle

Greeting Overflowers,

What is SQL Server 2008 R2's alternative to Oracle 11g RAC ?
How do they compare ?

I need to utilize cheap computers running the same database for mostly read-only parallel/distributed queries.

Regards

Comment: Parallel distributed queries. Have you tried other options? 1 box with a ton of RAM or 1 box with a ton of RAM and RAID Arrays? I've been down that route (distributed queries) with 10 really good servers and found that just 1 really good server could outperform the 10 due to network latency and traffic. MSSQL can be installed in a cluster, so you can use MSSQL 2008 R2 as the alternative.

Comment: How much data are we talking about. How many records and what disk space does the data occupy. What is the database schema design? How how have you figured you need a a cluster rather than just one box? What is cheap?

Comment: what is you data size and number of rows? What latency do you require?

Comment: Do you mean RAC as a high availability solution capable of node failure, or RAC as a way to add extra CPUs and memory to a set of data ?

Comment: Trying asking on www.serverfault.com

Answer (score -1):

mysql sounds like a cheap alternative on cheap hardware.  No OS licensing.  SQL Server is better than Oracle - or is it the other way around?  If you could list more requirements, recommendations might be made.